# d3 Preserve scale/translate after resetting range

Tags: d3.js

I have an `<svg>` whose width is 100% of its container. When the container is resized, I update the linear `xScale.range()` to represent the new resized width of the `<svg>`. Apparently, I then need to reapply the range to my zoom behaviour as outlined in the [zoom.x() documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#wiki-x):

> If the scale's domain or range is modified programmatically, this function should be called again. Setting the x-scale also resets the scale to 1 and the translate to [0, 0].

The resetting of the `scale` and `translate` is where I have a problem. If I have previously zoomed in before resizing, I call `zoom.x( xScale )` and now d3 thinks the chart's scale is 1 and translate is 0,0 therefore, I cannot zoom out or pan.

Is my approach to the way I handle the resize incorrect?

Comment: I suppose you have d3.behavior.zoom().x(xScale). So updating xScale's range on window resize without updating the zoom.x() won't do any harm, you just stay in your previously zoomed position and are able to zoom again in the resized window.

Comment: Thanks. The drawback with that approach is the zoom's center/focal point no longer matches the mouse position. Should I be attempting to correct that with `zoom.center()`? Think that's the best overall approach?

Comment: You can try update zoom.x() or zoom.center() and then call zoom.translate() explicitly within your resize() function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the best strategy is to cache the scale and translate values, reset, then reapply. For the record, this code (within my resize handler) roughly shows my solution:

```
// Cache scale
var cacheScale = zoom.scale();

// Cache translate
var cacheTranslate = zoom.translate();

// Cache translate values as percentages/ratio of the full width
var cacheTranslatePerc = zoom.translate().map( function( v, i, a )
{
  return (v * -1) / getFullWidth();
} );

// Manually reset the zoom
zoom.scale( 1 ).translate( [0, 0] );

// Update range values based on resized container dimensions
xScale.range( [0, myResizedContainerWidth] );

// Apply the updated xScale to the zoom
zoom.x( xScale );

// Revert the scale back to our cached value
zoom.scale( cacheScale );

// Overwrite the x value of cacheTranslate based on our cached percentage
cacheTranslate[0] = -(getFullWidth() * cacheTranslatePerc[0]);

// Finally apply the updated translate
zoom.translate( cacheTranslate );


function getFullWidth()
{
  return xScale.range()[1] * zoom.scale();
}
```

Comment: I am facing a similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412324/in-my-d3-chart-appended-rect-is-not-coming-properly can you guide me

Answer (score 4):

For those that stumbled upon this looking for a v4 solution, using the awesome setup from Philip above that is for v3, I adapted a loosely-based v4 solution. I spread out the variables to explain it the way v3 used to do it (since it makes more sense in v3). v4 does not have the ability to force the X value like v3 did, so you have to calculate out the existing X and then divide by the scale (K). (There may be a better way to do the final calculation + setting it on the zoom, but the d3-zoom documentation is a little confusing on this)

```
let transform = d3.zoomTransform(node);
let oldFullWidth = (oldWidth * transform.k);
let newFullWidth = (newWidth * transform.k);

// this is the result you want X to be
let newX = -(newFullWidth * ((transform.x * -1) / oldFullWidth));
// this is just deducting from the existing so you can call .translate
let translateBy = (newX - transform.x) / transform.k;
d3.select(node).call(myZoom.transform, transform.translate(translateBy, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still in D3v3 with one of my libraries, and have struggled off and on with this problem for years.

I think the principle of @Philip's solution is really great: since D3 wants to take the scales only when they represent translate `[0,0]` and scale `0`, save the zoom parameters and then reset the zoom to that state. And when replacing the scales, make sure they are also in the reset state.

I couldn't get Philip's code to work for me, perhaps because I need to set both dimensions, or perhaps because I need to resize the domain based on the new div size. But I think I came up with a nice generalization of his technique.

Taking it one step further, resetting the scale and translate on the zoom behavior will cause it to *change the domains of the scales* to where they should be for the reset state. Very helpful!

So now we can just

- multiply the scale domains by the ratio of new to old size
- set the ranges to the new div size
- plunk the scales (which are still untranslated and unscaled but a different size) back into the zoom
- restore the translate and scaling

At least, it worked for me!

Here's the source, with inputs `oldWidth`, `oldHeight`, `newWidth`, `newHeight` all in screen coordinates:

```
var scale = _zoom.scale(), translate = _zoom.translate();
_zoom.scale(1).translate([0,0]);
var xDomain = _diagram.x().domain(), yDomain = _diagram.y().domain();
_diagram.x()
    .domain([xDomain[0], xDomain[0] + (xDomain[1] - xDomain[0])*newWidth/oldWidth])
    .range([0, newWidth]);
_diagram.y()
    .domain([yDomain[0], yDomain[0] + (yDomain[1] - yDomain[0])*newHeight/oldHeight])
    .range([0, newHeight]);
_zoom
    .x(_diagram.x()).y(_diagram.y())
    .translate(translate).scale(scale);
```

I will be sure to check back when I port my library to D3v4.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412324/in-my-d3-chart-appended-rect-is-not-coming-properly can you guide me

Comment: I don't get what your question has to do with recreating the scale when the window changes size. Maybe you need to explain better your expected and actual behavior. [d3.js] is a tough tag for getting help, sorry.

Comment: On chart loads I am transforming the scale because first and last circle was cutting off as you can see in https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-monad-xw9dw, for fixing this i used `svg.call(zoom.transform, transform); //This is initial call on chart load`

Comment: I'm not sure what that does. Why not just initialize `xScale` with some padding, like `.range([10,width-10])`?

Comment: let me try this, I guess this will be better. instead of transforming.